# Restart Sidekiq If it fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, sidekiq, sidekiq-monitor

Is there a way to restart sidekiq automatically if it gets killed because of some issue on the server - may me memory etc.

right now i have to login to the server command line and run something like

```
bundle exec sidekiq -d -P tmp/sidekiq.pid -L log/sidekiq.log
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [Sidekiq wiki](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Deployment#running-your-own-process), there is a section about deployment, including upstart and systemd scripts. You can use those to ensure the process restarts appropriately.

Comment: thank you will check it out. Even though it speaks about when we push the deployment. I am sure we can figure how to monitor if sidekiq has gone numb.